# What Ruby construct does the link_to method in Rails use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Say I have this route:

```
  match '/somepage' => "home#somepage"
```

I can then do this on a different page to link to "somepage":

```
<%= link_to "Some Page", somepage_path %>
```

I'm new to both Ruby and Rails, and I'm struggling to understand how exactly the "somepage_path" part works. It's not a string, it's not a symbol, is it a method call? If so, where does that method exist? Seems like I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: Those are URL helper methods, similar to `link_to` itself, only that they are auto-generated by the routing system (maybe even implemented using `method_missing`, but I don't think so).

Comment: As Niklas points out, these are helper methods created by the routing system that are available in any of your views.  For more information:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

On initialization all paths are generated according to the routes.rb definitions.
If you want to customize the routes names you can use

```
match '/somepage' => "home#somepage", :as => "foobar"
```

Later used as

```
<%= link_to "Some Page", foobar_path %>
```

Hope that clears some stuff up about custom routing :)

Answer (score 0):

Link magic is all handled by `ActionDispatch::URL::UrlFor`, see [ActionDispatch::URL::UrlFor](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html)